# Auto stop SQL Server service while exiting SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I use SQL Server 2019 Development edition on my development machine. I do not use the SQL server always.

As SQL Server services eats much memory, I just don't want the services to run on back ground. I can do this manually, like before starting SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), run the `net start SQL_SERVICE_NAME` and after exiting SSMS, run the `net stop SQL_SERVICE_NAME`.

Anybody hear about an automated way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server and Management Studio are two different things. In most cases, people have installed one engine and management studio, but what if you have more engines on your PC installed for example SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2019. It is really hard to automate this part which server should be disabled or both etc.

In your case `Docker` is an option. It is easy to switch between database engines and you can easily stop and start service only when you needed. In the end, you haven't achieved much Docker is wasting your memory as well as directly installed SQL Server engine.

So, the last and probably best option is to setup **Manual** startup for SQL Server engine. You don't need to execute commands, because you can start and stop your SQL engine directly through SQL Server Management Studio. Most people know how to restart and stop the database engine through Management Studio, but the starting engine from this tool is quite tricky.

Open your management studio, go to the `View` and then `Registered Servers`. In the Local Server Groups with a right-click on the engine you can easily start and stop service, and of course, with a double click will open a new query session.

Maybe this can help you instead of trying to automate this part.

[image]